# What is a Suffix Automaton?

Tags: string, suffix-tree, suffix-array, automaton

Can someone please explain to me what exactly is a suffix automaton, and how it works and differs from suffix trees and suffix arrays? I have already tried searching on the web but was not able to come across any clear comprehensive explanation.

I found the following link closest to what I wanted but it is in Russian and the translation to English was difficult to understand.

http://e-maxx.ru/algo/suffix_automata

Answer (score 4):

A suffix automaton is a finite-state machine that recognizes all the suffixes of a string. There's a lot of resources on finite-state machines you can read, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) being a good start.

Suffix trees and suffix arrays are data structures containting all the suffixes of a string. There are multiple algorithms to build and act on these structures to perform operations efficiently on strings.

Answer (score 3):

**Suffix Machine:**

> Suffix machine (or a directed acyclic graph of words) is a powerful
>   data structure that allows to solve many string problems.
>
> *For example*, using the suffix of the machine, you can search for all
>   occurrences of one string into another, or to count the number of
>   different substrings of the given string - both tasks it can solve in
>   linear time.
>
> On an intuitive level, suffix automaton can be understood as concise
>   information about all the substrings of a given string. An impressive
>   fact is that the suffix automaton contains all the information in such
>   a concise form, which for a string of length n it requires only a O(n)
>   memory. Moreover, it can also be built over time O(n) (if we consider
>   the size of the alphabet k constant; otherwise, during O (n log k)).
>
> **Historically**, the first linear size suffix of the machine was opened in 1983 Blumer and others, and in 1985 - 1986 he was presented
>   the first algorithms build in linear time (Crochemore, Blumer and
>   others). For more detail see references at the end of the article.
>
> In *English* the suffix machine called "suffix automaton" (in the plural
>   - "suffix automata"), and a directed acyclic graph of the words "directed acyclic word graph (or simply "DAWG").

**The definition of the suffix automaton:**

> Definition. The suffix automaton for the given string s is called a
>   minimal deterministic finite automaton that accepts all suffixes of
>   the string s.
>
> We will explain this definition.
>
> - Suffix automaton is a directed acyclic graph, in which vertices are    called States, and the arcs of the graph is the transitions between
>     these States.
> - One of the States t_0 is called the initial state, and it must be the    origin of the graph (i.e. it achievable for all other States).
> - Each transition in the automaton is arc marked with some symbol. All    transitions originating from any state must have different
>     labels.    (On the other hand, may not be transitions for any
>     characters.)
> - One or more of the conditions marked as terminal States. If we go    from the initial state t_0 any way to any terminal state, and let us
>     write this label all arcs traversed, you get a string, which must be
>     one of the suffixes of the string s.
> - The suffix automaton contains the minimum number of vertices among    all the machines that satisfy the above conditions. (The minimum
>     number of transitions is not required because the condition of
>     minimality of the number of States in the machine may not be "extra"
>     ways - otherwise it would break the previous property.)

**Elementary properties of the suffix automaton:**

> The simplest, and yet most important property of the suffix automaton
>   is that it contains information about all the substrings of the string
>   s. Namely, any path from the initial state t_0 if we write out the
>   labels of the arcs along this path, forms necessarily a substring of a
>   string s. Conversely, any substring of the string s corresponds to
>   some path starting in the initial state t_0.
>
> In order to simplify the explanation, we will say that a substring
>   corresponds to the path from the initial state, the labels along which
>   form the substring. Conversely, we will say that any path corresponds
>   to one row which is formed by the labels of its arcs.
>
> In each state machine suffix is one or more paths from the initial
>   state. Let's say that the state corresponds to the set of strings that
>   match all of these ways.

**EXAMPLES:**

[image]